# How to spend the last week with your dog

Tags: dogs, death

My mom told me on Saturday that our dog Max has cancer and internal bleeding caused by a ruptured spleen. We'll put him to sleep on Friday, January 29th. I want his last week to be happy, how can I spend this last week with him so that he can be happy?

By the way, he's a German Shepherd and Labrador mix, he's around 8 or 9 years old, and he's a big doofy dog, a gentle giant.

Comment: If the vet says activity is OK take him to some of his favorite spots. One week is hard for you to prepare but do what you can. Tell friends and neighbors that may want to say goodbye.

Comment: My standard observation: "We don't have them long enough. But they have us all their lives.  That's not a.bad thing."

Comment: Do anything and everything that he enjoys. Let him know he is loved and spend plenty of time with him. Take him places he loves, give him food he loves. Cuddles. Endless cuddles.

Answer (score 4):

I am so, so sorry for this sad news.  I know it's difficult, but you need to understand that this last week is really for you.  Your dog is happy just being with you.  I would suggest taking the week off work (or working from home, if this is possible).  Just be with him.  That's all he wants.  It doesn't really matter what you *do*. You will feel comfort knowing you spent his last week with him.

This week is for you to come to peace that you did everything you could to keep him happy and healthy.  It seems like you really love him and have taken good care of him.  Focus on knowing that you gave him a good, happy life that he may not have gotten with another owner.

My thoughts and prayers are with you both.